# Iterating over hierachical nested data and building html from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hierarchical

I'm a bit mentally stuck in processing some data in JS with that I'm outputting from my API.

What the backend is outputing is a category list that can be nested up to N-th level.

What I'm trying to do is generate a nice nested structure for them so that they represent the JSON structure but in the DOM:

```
<div>
    Women's Fashion
    <div>
        Women's Clothes
        <div>Dresses</div>
        <div>Watches</div>
        <div>Etc.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        Watches
    </div>
    <div>
        Jewellery
        <div>Swarowski</div>
        <div>Other</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's a good way for me to achieve this structure?

Here is a sample of the data I'm outputing. The key stuff here is that each Category can have a M-number of subcategories and the end-depth is not actually limited.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Women's Fashion",
            "hashtag": "#womensfashion",
            "parent_id": null,
            "parents_list": [],
            "product_count": 9466,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Womens Clothes",
                    "hashtag": "#womensclothes",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 2940,
                    "subcategories": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "Dresses",
                            "hashtag": "#dresses",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Tops",
                            "hashtag": "#womenstops",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 5,
                            "name": "Outwear",
                            "hashtag": "#womensoutwear",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 6,
                            "name": "Shirts",
                            "hashtag": "#womensshirts",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "Pants and Shorts",
                            "hashtag": "#womenspantsandshorts",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "name": "Skirts",
                            "hashtag": "#skirts",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 9,
                            "name": "Jeans",
                            "hashtag": "#womensjeans",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 10,
                            "name": "Lingerie and Nightweare",
                            "hashtag": "#lingerieandnightweare",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 12,
                            "name": "Muslimawear",
                            "hashtag": "#womensmuslimawear",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 109,
                            "name": "Other Womensclothes",
                            "hashtag": "#otherwomensclothes",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 135,
                            "name": "Sweaters and Jackets",
                            "hashtag": "#womenssweatersandjackets",
                            "parent_id": 2,
                            "parents_list": [
                                2,
                                1
                            ],
                            "product_count": null,
                            "subcategories": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "name": "Bags, Purses and Wallets",
                    "hashtag": "#womensbags",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 1626,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "name": "Shoes",
                    "hashtag": "#womensshoes",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 811,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "name": "Watches",
                    "hashtag": "#womenswatches",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 513,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "name": "Eyewear",
                    "hashtag": "#womenseyewear",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 145,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "name": "Jewellery",
                    "hashtag": "#womensjewellery",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 289,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 110,
                    "name": "Other Womensfashion",
                    "hashtag": "#otherwomensfashion",
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "parents_list": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "product_count": 129,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm thinking I need to do here is declare a function which goes over a tier and returns everything. Like

```
process_category(category)
{
    let html = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < category.length; i++)
    {
        let nested_html = null;
        if(i.subcategories.length > 0)
        {
            nested_html = process_category(i.subcategories);
        }
        let new_html = [
            <ListItem
                    primaryText={i.name}
                    onTouchTap={this.click_category.bind(this, i.id)}
                    nestedItems={[nested_html]}
            />
        ];
        html = [...html, ...new_html];
    }
    return(html);
}
```

EDIT:
Feeling incredibly stupud for not realizing how Javascript for/each works (was writing a python `for x in categories: print x.name`)

The fixed code which works but I'm not sure is optimal:

```
process_category(category)
{
    let html = [];
    for(var i in category)
    {
        let nested_html = null;
        if(category[i].subcategories.length > 0)
        {
            nested_html = this.process_category(category[i].subcategories);
        }
        let new_html = [
            <ListItem
                    primaryText={category[i].name}
                    // onTouchTap={this.click_category.bind(this, category[i].id)}
                    nestedItems={nested_html}
            />
        ];
        html = [...html, ...new_html];
    }
    return(html);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Comment: Sorry I noticed it was very incomplete I just edited with something I attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend recursion:

```
function generateDom(obj) {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(obj.name);
  node.appendChild(textnode);          
  for (var i in obj.subcategories) {
    var subcategory = obj.subcategories[i];
    node.append(generateDom(subcategory));
  }
  return node;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/fdk2m2ua/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reactjs based fiddle that may get you in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/giladaya/yo4xa3z1/4/

Main thing to note is the use of a recursive component:

```
const Item = function(props) {
  let { data } = props
  let children
  if (data.subcategories.length > 0) {
    children = (
      <div className={`level-${props.level}`}>
        {data.subcategories.map((item, idx) =>
          <Item data={item} level={props.level+1} key={`item-${idx}`}/>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    children = null
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {data.name}
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```